# Reducing .mdf file size

Tags: sql-server, configuration, disk-space, shrink, filegroups

I have a drive, `:d`, in my server where I have my *.mdf* file stored and now all of a sudden I notice that the drive `:d` has no space left.

When I checked the *.mdf* file of the database `demo1`, it is 1.6TB and occupies the entire drive `:d`. That is an important database and I cannot truncate tables in there.

I checked the database properties and noticed that the initial size of the *.mdf* is given as 1.6TB by the person who created the database.

How can I reduce the *.mdf* file size now? I tried shrinking, but it didn't help.

Any idea is helpful.

Comment: Have you reviewed [existing questions about shrinking MDFs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24449/shrinking-mdf-file), here on DBA.SE?

Comment: Yes.Sine the initial size is set as 1.6TB ,the minimum shrink size is also 1.6TB.I want o reduce the initial size so that i can shrink it to a smaller size > inital size.

Comment: `DBCC SHRINKFILE` will reduce the size of an MDF, *if* there's free space available to release.  What exactly was the outcome?  Is there free space in the file?  If not, you'll need to delete records, drop indices, compact tables, etc.  Is that the part with which you need help?

Comment: yes.There is virtually no free space available.I checked using SSMS and it shows only 407 MB free space available.And when i try to shrink it shows the minimum shrink size as 1.6TB.so there is no way i can shrink.

Comment: yes.I want to somehow reduce initial size if possible or else i have to delete records,drop indices etc.Or can i take a backup and then delete the database and then restore it with less initial size.?

Comment: @user9516827 - If you are on at least [SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/), you might consider using compression.

Comment: Why no one is talking about the initial size?

Comment: "Why no one is talking about the initial size?" Because if there is only 407 MB free in the file, the initial size doesn't matter -- you won't be able to shrink the file.

Comment: @DougDeden : When the database was created if the initial file size of .mdf was kept as 1GB then ,then i could have shrinked the mdf to 1 GB ryt?

Comment: @user9516827 - Have a look at [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22661.sql-server-misleading-database-initial-size-label.aspx)

Comment: @ScottHodgin :So if the data is 2TB,the mdf file will show as 2TB even if the initial size was small during the database creation.ryt?

Comment: There is not such as initial size recorded by SQL Server. The GUI show that, but it is wrong, and the word "initial" has been removed in SSMS 18 (per my request :-) ). So don't let that confuse you. Just do the shrink, and you can try using TRUNCATEONY first and see if that gets you anywhere (it doesn't move any data around). If not, then you have to do it without TRUNCATEONLY.

Comment: You can use TreeSize program to find the biggest archives it's free and lightweight it's usually the LDF that gets that big you can shrink all mdfs anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand, I can think of four things filling up your MDFs:

1. Data; records in tables.  If you can archive and delete  unneeded records, you can free space.
2. Indices.  You can query `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` for information about which indices are rarely used, and *consider* dropping some.  There's a risk that an index that looks safe to delete is part of an important long-running query, so ideally, you'd test your database and typical workload without the index before making a change to production.
3. Fragmentation (really, an extension of #1 and #2).  Badly fragmented tables and indices can take up [several times as much space](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/why-might-a-tables-data-space-take-up-4x-the-size-of-the-raw-data), which hurts performance as well as consuming your disks.
4. Free space.  Any records or indices you delete are not immediately freed to the file system, they're just made available to other tables and indices.  That's a good thing, [leave it there](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/)!  In *specific* circumstances, it may make sense to reclaim that space (using `DBCC SHRINKFILE`), but usually only when you've made a major structural change and you do not expect to need that space again.

If you can't delete data, and you can't add disks, in the short run you may be able to buy time by dropping indices and defragmenting tables and indices.  Both of those should be part of your regular maintenance, as a DBA.  Reviewing indices requires human intelligence, but defragmentation can [easily be automated](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/when-should-i-rebuild-indexes).

LDFs are another matter, and tend to bloat when you have long-running transactions and/or too few backups.  If that's also an issue, there are several questions and answers here on DBA.SE you can peruse.

Comment: Scott Hodgins brought up compression which is an excellent point, and which reminds me: well-chosen data types can take up less space.  If you have columns of `BIGINT` where `INT` would do, for example, that'll shave four bytes per field, per record.  `VARDECIMAL` can help a little too.

Comment: This server is not a production server,so can i just take a backup of the database and then delete the original database and restore it again with less initial size.?

Comment: You could take a backup, restore it somewhere else, make deletions, back it up again, and restore it again on the original server.  I don't know why, though; you'd have to make the original server read-only during this process, whereas it could remain online if you delete and defrag in situ.

Comment: Just to make it clear, RESTORE will create the database with the same size as it had when BACKUP was performed. So backup/restore in itself isn't a way to reduce size if a database.